# Using \def in \psplot

Tags: pstricks

For reasons I cannot explain `\def`'s don't seem to always work in/with `\psplot` as shown below

```
\documentclass[english, landscape, a4paper]{slides}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=4pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{pspicture*}(-1.5,-1)(1.5,1.5)
            \def\tI{0.0}
            \psplot{0.0}{1.0}{x \tI sub}   % does not work
            % \psplot{0.0}{1.0}{x \tI sub} % works
        \end{pspicture*}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I compile the above file with `xelatex file` and get the error

```
Error: /undefined in 0.0sub
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   0.0   0.0
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %s
  --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_
pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %error
ingval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nos
...
** WARNING ** Filtering file via command -->mgs.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -s
yLevel=1.3 -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorIm
/FlateEncode -dUseFlateCompression=t
```

Can someone please suggest a workaround for this problem?

Comment: use `\space` after `\tl`

Comment: Use: \psplot{0.0}{1.0}{x \tI\space sub}

Comment: Just to add why: the space after `\tI` gets ignored while reading the input (it follows a command name) and the error line `0.0sub` shows it. However, the common trick of putting `{}` after the command can't work here, while `\space` does the right thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments for your MWE:

1. When you want to get a tight, separate PDF output for each `pspicture`, you can use `standalone` class instead of `preview` package to save some keystrokes.
2. Only use `graphicx` (the modern one) and it loads `graphics` internally.
3. Remove unnecessary packages.
4. No need to use `center` environment if you need to generate a tight, separate PDF output for each `pspicture`.
5. Only use `pspicture*` to trim the objects outside the canvas. If no objects outside the canvas exist, just use `pspicture` without stars.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1.5,-1)(1.5,1.5)
\def\tI{0.0}
\psplot{0.0}{1.0}{x \tI\space sub}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Now let's discuss your problem. Control words will eat spaces following them. So `x \tI sub` becomes `x 0.0sub` that is no meaning. To preserve the spaces, you need to use `\space` as shown in the code above.

### Another solution:

Make sure  you put at least one space before the closing `}` in your macro definition. See the code below.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1.5,-1)(1.5,1.5)
\def\tI{0.0 }% can you see there is one space before the closing }?
\psplot{0.0}{1.0}{x \tI sub}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I don't need to add an animated version.

Answer (score 2):

use always a definition with a space at the end:

```
\def\tI{0.0 }
```

then you do not need the `\space` macro for the function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: it could be good idea that you read the question!

Comment: It's the same what  ガベージコレクタ did and also commented in his code. So your answer is nothing additional and should, in my humble opinion be a comment to  ガベージコレクタ's answer.